# Android - BitMap Null From URL

Tags: android, bitmap

When i was trying to get the bitmap image from facebook url, it showing bitmap is null. here is my code.

```
URL url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/100006480449004/picture?type=large");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: there is apparently a redirection here. You probably need to tell httpUrlConnection to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the URL into your browser, this will forward you to the correct URL of the pic, ending on `.jpg`

Or you enable redirecting via `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);`